# execute command after asterisk confbridge recording is finished

Tags: asterisk, conference

I'm trying to find answer how to make Asterisk execute some command (my script) after confbridge's recording is finished

There is the next info in confbridge.conf:

> record_conference=yes
>
> Records the conference call starting when the first user enters the
>   room, and ending when the last user exits the room.

It records file well but I want it sending wav file via email.

Could anybody help me?

My config now looks like this (if it's necessary):

> exten => 333,1,ConfBridge(100010,100010_bridge_profile,100010_user_profile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialplan scripting is limited to events relating to each call channel. To get event info for other parts of asterisk (such as the ConfBridge application) you should hook into the [Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239).

There are [many libraries](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API) already created to make working with the AMI easier. (That site may be outdated. Refer to the official Asterisk Wiki whenever possible.)

The AMI event you're interested in is "ConfBridgeEnd". Docs [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge).

Answer (score 0):

You can use h-extension after confbridge, in which you have check if confbridge still active(last user).

If yes, run your script via System call.